# DevExpress TreeList not displaying child nodes and displaying as root nodes instead

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, treelist, xtratreelist

I have a `TreeList` reading from a `List(Of LedgerAccountEntry)()`.

```
Public Class LedgerAccountEntry
    Public Property LedgerAccountSys() As Integer 
    Public ParentLedgerAccountSys As Integer
    '
    '
    ' ETC
End Class
```

In form load:

```
tlLedgerAccounts.ParentFieldName = "ParentLedgerAccountSys"
tlLedgerAccounts.KeyFieldName = "LedgerAccountSys"
tlLedgerAccounts.RootValue = -1
```

Later on:

```
While bla
    entry.LedgerAccountSys = rstAccounts("LedgerAccountSys").Value
    entry.ParentLedgerAccountSys = IIf(rstAccounts("ParentLedgerAccountSys").Value Is DBNull.Value, -1, rstAccounts("ParentLedgerAccountSys").Value)
    lst.add(entry)
End While            
tlLedgerAccounts.DataSource = lst
```

These are just the relevant parts. Please let me know if you need more info.

The result is flat tree with no child nodes, I checked that the IDs exists and are being returned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `ParentLedgerAccountSys` as field. You need to convert your `ParentLedgerAccountSys` to property or add another property which represents your `ParentLedgerAccountSys` field.
Here is example:

```
Public Class LedgerAccountEntry
    Public Property LedgerAccountSys As Integer
    'Public ParentLedgerAccountSys As Integer <-- Here is field.
    Public Property ParentLedgerAccountSys As Integer '<-- Here is property instead of field.
    '
    '
    ' ETC
End Class
```