# Bind a record in Treelist

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I'm facing issue in binding single row to the treelist. In my application I have a two forms. first form contains treelist it will contain list of rows.

I need a selected row from the list. Using

```
public object selectedRow
{
return treelist.GetDataRecordByNode(treelist.FocusedNode)
}
```

using this code I get the selected row.

In second Form, I'm trying to bind that row.

```
public void row(selectedRow)
{
treelist2.DataSource=selectedRow; //I get the row value here.
}
```

But data not able to shown in second treelist. what step I need to do to bind a selectedrow to second treelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the DataSource should be an IEnumerable-type.
try something like this (pseudo-code ahead):

```
public void row(selectedRow)
{
      List<yourType> list = new List<yourType>();
      list.Add(selectedRow);
      treelist2.DataSource=list; 
}
```

Comment: Its shows error in list.Add(selectedRow) list does not contain add method

Answer (score 0):

Please go through TreeList's [Data Binding](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2434/Controls-and-Libraries/Tree-List) section, [Data Binding](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5553) topic provides the complete information on binding the TreeList to data.

You can find reference to bind it with class objects here - 
[Binding Controls to Data Created at Runtime](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2387/Common-Features/Data-Binding/Binding-Controls-to-Data-Created-at-Runtime)

In your row method, you should either create a `List<ClassType>` or `BindingList<ClassType>` before assigning the data source property. A list of ClassType objects can be created and bound to a data-aware control as follows:

```
BindingList<ClassType> list = new BindingList<ClassType>();
treelist2.DataSource = list;
```

References:
[DevExpress TreeList not displaying child nodes and displaying as root nodes instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216380/devexpress-treelist-not-displaying-child-nodes-and-displaying-as-root-nodes-inst?rq=1)
[binding data to the treelist control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768986/binding-data-to-the-treelist-control?rq=1)
[Binding data in DevExpress Treelist from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157302/binding-data-in-devexpress-treelist-from-database?rq=1)